# Get those who didnt match

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two users

The User 1 profile_id

```
3734387944
```

then the User 2 Profile_id

```
1421536173
```

there is a table named friends with a structure of

```
from_profile_id
to_profile_id
request
blocked_by
```

and this is the data and structure of users

```
var_id  profile_id  fullname             firstname   lastname
180     3734387944  John Louis Domincel  John Louis  Domincel  
181     1421536173  James Domincel       James       Domincel
```

and this is the data and structure of friends

```
from_profile_id  to_profile_id  request  blocked_by
3734387944       1421536173     3        3734387944
```

and this is the data and structure of post

```
id   profile_id   text 
1    3734387944   POST OF USER 1
2    1421536173   POST OF USER 2
```

Using this Query, I can select all post of every user

```
SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY var_id DESC
```

But i want to filter it: 
User 1 has blocked user 2 so both of them cannot receive each user post, Same Function. If not friends, But if they are friends the data will show up in each user.

```
Request Legend
1 = Friend Request
2 = Friends
3 = Blocked
```

I have tried this Another Query: But User 1 can see the user 2 posts while user 2 cannot see User 1 post if blocked only. I want to 
modify it and make the two of them cannot see each user posts if Blocked and not Friends

```
SELECT u.*,f.*
FROM post AS u
LEFT JOIN friends AS f
ON f.blocked_by = u.profile_id AND
f.blocked_by <> "3734387944" AND
(
f.to_profile_id = "3734387944" OR
f.from_profile_id = "3734387944"
) AND
f.request = 3
WHERE f.from_profile_id IS NULL
```

Here's a DB-FIDDLE [LINK](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/226Wiq4GxXpQqKRnQJFWuy/6)

Comment: Isn't post_id primary key in the posts table ? You have post_id = 1 twice.

Comment: you could simply check if its empty or null if not a sub select with a CASE to get the correct user id for matching.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya edited just now

Comment: @JohnLouisDomincel please try to create a https://www.db-fiddle.com/ It helps when lots of tables involved.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/226Wiq4GxXpQqKRnQJFWuy/6

Comment: @LawrenceCherone can u give me more sample sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment use a CASE statement sub-select to get the correct users id, the rest is then just a normal select.

```
...
WHERE u.profile_id IN (
  SELECT CASE WHEN blocked_by = ? THEN from_profile_id ELSE to_profile_id END AS friend_id 
  FROM friends
  WHERE (from_profile_id = ? OR to_profile_id = ?) AND request = 1
)
...
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9K3wy4tqRKVGgvvyxvkgMS/0

Comment: can i combine it with one query

Comment: not that im aware of as you basically got two columns but only one is right to match so you need to find out the correct id to match, whats wrong with a sub select? this is common for social table i.e friends/messages structure where you dont want to have two rows.